# How to vertically pile items in mobile/tablet view in html/css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media-queries

I am working on a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zaefnson/embedded/result/) which is working perfectly fine in a desktop view.

The desktop view works in a way that on click of any 2 product items **(By default, one remain selected)** , the description box gets displayed at the bottom giving detailed explanation of those product items.

The snippets of CSS codes which I have used for the mobile view:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
{
.product-all-contents
{
   overflow-x: auto;
}

.product-contents .product{
  min-width: 50.795%;
  margin: 0 2%;
    padding-top: 3.91%;
    padding-left: 3.91%;    padding-right: 3.91%;
  }
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

**In the mobile view**, there is one small issue. The issue is that, **I am seeing the explanation of both product items whereas only one should be displayed without changing the look of it i.e. items should remain piled up**.

I want the mobile view to work exactly in a way as in the desktop view i.e. when we click one product item, the description box should display at the bottom and when we click another product item another description box should display at the bottom.

The reason why I have used **display:inline-block !important** because I want the items to pile up vertically in mobile view in html/css. Removing that will make the images and text squished.

Comment: Just remove **display: inline-block !important;** from **@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)**. It will solve your problem

Comment: It will not solve my problem. Check my problem statement again.

Comment: My problem statement explains my question much better.

Comment: You stated that only one should be displayed @user5447339

Comment: Yes only one should be displayed but without changing the look of the mobile view. Removing `display: inline-block !important` changes the look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of you have set `display: inline-block !important;` for `div.franchisehubtv` and `div.cloudbasedtextipad` in `@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)` which `override` your `display: none;` css.

> Solution No: 1

You can remove those classes from the media query, so your `@media` will be like this

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
{
div.goal-setting, div.customization-tools, div.custom-invoicing, div.lead-tracking, div.email-marketing, div.royalty-calculator, div.brand-control, div.business-analytics,div.tech-support, div.employee-management, div.order-management, div.white-label  {
  display: inline-block !important;
}
.cloudbasedtextipad, .franchisehubtv {
   flex-direction: column;
 }
.tv img {
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
  }
}
```

> Solution No: 2

You need to override those `css` by adding these lines

```
div.franchisehubtv[style="display: none;"] {
    display: none !important;
}
div.cloudbasedtextipad[style="display: none;"] {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zaefnson/3/)

> **Update**: You can set your layout using `flex` for small devices

Comment: Can you update it in the fiddle ? In that way, I will be able to visualize.

Comment: Ok, so I think you misunderstood my question. Can you read my problem statement of the question ?

Comment: The reason why I have used `display:inline-block !important` because I want the items to piled up vertically (text and mobile) in mobile view

Comment: if you are facing problem of squished text and images, you can use `@media` to set those elements please check here https://jsfiddle.net/zaefnson/3/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172381/discussion-between-zuber-and-user5447339).

Comment: Yes that solves my problem. Instead of using `display: inline-block` I should be using `flex-direction: column` Thanks !

Comment: if this helped you, consider accept the answer :) @user5447339

Comment: Accepted. I will let you know if I have any question.

Comment: Sure, I'll try to clear your doubts with the best solution

Answer (score 0):

Didn't get you clearly, can you please specify is this mobile view the one you want to be the same display in desktop? if so then i recommend you to check how to use bootstrap grid system and you can use their CSS as a benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your current solution, the second div has a style rule that is invoked below 767px, which forces it to display as an inline-block. By adding the !important declaration, this then overrides any other property declaration.

If you remove this rule, you'll get a broken layout, but the div is hidden as required.

As to the layout, the content within each div will need some refined flexbox rules, which can use the same breakpoint to switch between column or row direction:

```
flex-direction: column (for mobile)
flex-direction: row (for non-mobile)
```

Comment: Can you my problem statement of the question ?

Comment: I've updated the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zaefnson/4/) to show the amends required.

Namely, replace the display: inline-block rule, with the flex-direction: column rule. This will show the content of each div in a column based format.

I've added a rule for the images to show at a max-width of 100%, and setting their height to auto. This stops the images from spilling out of the container.

Answer (score 0):

One problem you have is because you set the display property as inline style in the HTML, so you have to use `important` to overwrite.
The second problem is that you are not having in count the `display: inline-block` on your jQuery.

You are going to have to change several things, I've changed the fiddle to account for these things, only works if you click in the buttons, on load you see both items, there are several ways you can do these things, I only want to make the minimal changes to show the result.

https://jsfiddle.net/zaefnson/2/

And on desktop probably doesn't work either, just like I said, there are several things you are going to have to change.